# server socket hanging on child proc

Tags: c, sockets, server, multiprocessing

I'm having some trouble abstracting some functions from my server. Specifically my parsing func's are really hard to debug while inside the child proc's and I can't even follow it in gdb because the server is jumping the loop when I follow the child proc?? I think it might be easier to show the code than butcher the context in my words..

main spawning loop

```
while (1) { /* accepting client connections */
        addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);

        /* create worker and accept traffic on listen_sock */
        printf("Waiting for client connection\n");
        if ((worker_sock = accept(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &addrlen)) < 0) {
            perror("Error accepting traffic on socket:"); continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(client_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *) &client_addr), s, sizeof(s));
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) {                       // this is the child process
            close(listen_sock);               // child doesn't need the listener
            respond(worker_sock);             // send response to client
//            shutdown(worker_sock, SHUT_RDWR); // block connections
            close(worker_sock);               // destroy that old sock!
            exit(0);                          // exit proc
        }                                     // end of child proc
        close(worker_sock);                   // parent doesn't need this
    }
```

Respond function (called by child)

```
/* serve response for client request */
void respond(int worker_sock) {
    char *request[3], path[PATH_MAX] = {'\0'};
    char recv_data[SOCK_BUFF_DEF_READ] = {'\0'};
    char resp_data[SOCK_BUFF_DEF_WRITE] = {'\0'};
    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
    int resourcefd;

    /* TODO: change this to terminate on client req flag (header w/ size of req) */
    /* read into buff full request */
    if ((bytes_read = recv(worker_sock, recv_data, SOCK_BUFF_DEF_READ, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, ("recv() error\n"));
    } printf("File: %s\nFunction: %s()\nLine Number: %d\nbytes_read: %d, MAX: %d\n",__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__, bytes_read, SOCK_BUFF_MAX_READ);
    /* error checking buffer overflow checking */
    if (bytes_read == 0 || bytes_read > SOCK_BUFF_MAX_READ) {
        fprintf(stderr, ("recv() error\n"));
        /* send error response */
    }

    Request request00 = parseRequest(recv_data);
```

In progress abstraction of parser

```
typedef struct request Request;
struct request {
    unsigned char    info;        /*   request method / proto     */
    char            *path;        /*   path to resource   */
    Dict            *headers;     /*   http headers       */
    char            *body;        /*   body of request   */
};


/* parse request line from a client request */
Request parseRequest(char *req) {
    int i;

    printf("processing client request\n");
    size_t *num_tokens = malloc(sizeof(size_t));           /* num of tokens */

    char **tokens = strsplit(req, " \r\n", num_tokens);     /* parse it */
    printf("File: %s\nFunction: %s()\nLine Number: %d\n",__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
    printf("num_tokens: %zi\n", *num_tokens);

    for (i = 0; i < *num_tokens; i++) {
        printf("token: %s\n", tokens[i]);
    }

    printf("File: %s\nFunction: %s()\nLine Number: %d\n",__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
    Request retreq = {
            .info = 0,                                      /* method, proto, validity */
            .path = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *)),        /* request path or URI */
            .headers = initDict(50),                        /* limit to 50 headers */
            .body = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *))         /* body of request */
    };


    return retreq;
}
```

I determined that the child is getting hung on the strSplit function (my implementation of strtok_r) but that function has been tested thoroughly and still works in my other implementations so I am kind of stumped on why the child's context differs in the calling this function, the strsplit is posted below as well.

strSplit

```
char **strsplit(char *str, const char delims[], size_t *len) {
    char *save;              /* holds str_tok val btwn calls */
    char **result = '\0';    /* set result to NULL */
    char *tmp = strdup(str); /* leaves original str intact */
    size_t delims_size = strlen(delims);
    size_t count = 0;        /* number of main strings */
    size_t sub_count = 0;    /* number of substrings */

    /* get number of delims in str and malloc */
    while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, delims)) != NULL) {
        tmp += delims_size;
        count++;
    }
    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result) {
        /*  reset counter and tmp   */
        count = 0;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = strdup(str);
        /*   grab the first token   */
        char* token = strtok_r(tmp, delims, &save);
        result[count] = strdup(token);

        while (token) {
            token = strtok_r(NULL, delims, &save);
            if (token != NULL) {
                result[++count] = strdup(token);
            }
            else { /* set last ptr to NULL */
                result[++count] = '\0';
            }/* add one for trailing token */
        } *len = count;
    }
    else {
        *len = 0;
    }
    free(tmp);
    return result;
}
```

If anyone has an idea how to better go about debugging this i am all ears.. When setting gdb with "set follow-fork-mode child" it attemps to follow child but parent jumps out of the loop (it should be infinite until signal stops it) and thus ends the program..

Comment: `strtok()` and friends don't block. I suggest for the moment that you get rid of the `fork()` and debug it all in a single process. You won't be handling multiple clients while debugging.

Comment: okay it was way simpler than I thought but here is my question.. On this line: if (tmp) free(tmp); tmp = strdup(str);  Do i need to free the tmp ptr before calling strdup again?? I know it will try to malloc the ptr again and I thought that would leave a chunk of memory somewhere on the heap or will it replace the one that is already written to that ptr?

Comment: Looks like it is throwing a SIGABRT on the free statement prior to return, even when I remove the prior free() statement it still throws sigabrt on line 89 of strSplit()

Comment: to get `gdb` to stop at the beginning of the child process, place a breakpoint on the first line of code in the child process

Comment: the problem was trying to free the tmp ptr but I end up advancing it until it contains nothing and i guess free() is trying to say that it is null